# windows 10 on core 2 duo with 2 GB ram

Tags: windows-10

I am using pc with core 2 duo e7300 processor with 2 GB ram will I be able to use Windows 10(64 bit) properly on this pc or I need to increase my ram

Comment: Why do you want to use a 64-bit OS with so little memory?  You should verify your system even supports more than 2 GB.  **Most Core 2 Duo systems didn’t**

Comment: @Ramhound then what should I do

Comment: Get newer hardware that supports W10.

Comment: Will it work if I expand my ram to 4gb